# Monthly Averages Using Daily Data Using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a text file with four columns: year, month, day and snow depth. This is daily data for a 30-year period, 1979-2009.

I would like to calculate 360 (30yrs X 12 months) individual monthly averages using pandas (i.e. isolating all the values for Jan-1979, Feb-1979,... Dec-2009 and averaging each). Can anyone help me out with some example code?

```
1979    1   1   3
1979    1   2   3
1979    1   3   3
1979    1   4   3
1979    1   5   3
1979    1   6   3
1979    1   7   4
1979    1   8   5
1979    1   9   7
1979    1   10  8
1979    1   11  16
1979    1   12  16
1979    1   13  16
1979    1   14  18
1979    1   15  18
1979    1   16  18
1979    1   17  18
1979    1   18  20
1979    1   19  20
1979    1   20  20
1979    1   21  20
1979    1   22  20
1979    1   23  18
1979    1   24  18
1979    1   25  18
1979    1   26  18
1979    1   27  18
1979    1   28  18
1979    1   29  18
1979    1   30  18
1979    1   31  19
1979    2   1   19
1979    2   2   19
1979    2   3   19
1979    2   4   19
1979    2   5   19
1979    2   6   22
1979    2   7   24
1979    2   8   27
1979    2   9   29
1979    2   10  32
1979    2   11  32
1979    2   12  32
1979    2   13  32
1979    2   14  33
1979    2   15  33
1979    2   16  33
1979    2   17  34
1979    2   18  36
1979    2   19  36
1979    2   20  36
1979    2   21  36
1979    2   22  36
1979    2   23  36
1979    2   24  31
1979    2   25  29
1979    2   26  27
1979    2   27  27
1979    2   28  27
```

Comment: Can you add example data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compute daily climatology using pandas python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973527/compute-daily-climatology-using-pandas-python)

Comment: @dawg Added two months worth of data. Like I said, though, I have it going through Dec. 31, 2009.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll want to group your data by year and month, and then calculate the mean of each group.  Pseudo-code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Read in your file as a pandas.DataFrame
# using 'any number of whitespace' as the seperator
df = pd.read_csv("snow.txt", sep='\s*', names=["year", "month", "day", "snow_depth"])

# Show the first 5 rows of the DataFrame
print df.head()

# Group data first by year, then by month
g = df.groupby(["year", "month"])

# For each group, calculate the average of only the snow_depth column
monthly_averages = g.aggregate({"snow_depth":np.mean})
```

For more, about the split-apply-combine approach in Pandas, read [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

A [DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) is a:

> "Two-dimensional size-mutable, potentially heterogeneous tabular data structure with labeled axes (rows and columns)."

For your purposes, the difference between a numpy `ndarray` and a `DataFrame` are not too significant, but DataFrames have a bunch of functions that will make your life easier, so I'd suggest doing some reading on them.

Comment: Could you provide a little more information on the data frame? I'm used to np.genfromtxt which reads in each column individually, but every tutorial I see has the year, month and day combined into one variable from the onset.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a working example, and added a little bit of information regarding DataFrames.  Suffice it to say, if you end up using Pandas for data analysis, you will almost certainly end up using DataFrames at some point.

Comment: Awesome. This helps immensely. And yeah, I do plan on doing more with Pandas so this is a great jumping-off point.

Comment: what is the index is `datetime64` timestamps instead of having year and month as separate columns?