# Exclude one day data from time series xarray dataset

Tags: python, python-xarray

I am trying to drop one day data `'2020-01-30'` from `xarray` time series dataset `ds` using Python. Following code doesn't work:

```
ds_1 = ds.where(ds.time != '2020-01-30', drop=True)
```

The code runs but returns the same result.

Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376113/removing-leap-day-from-leap-years-in-xarray-dataset) link.

```
ds_1 = ds.drop([np.datetime64('2020-01-30')], dim='time')
```